# Can Monero support smart contracts

Tags: smart-contracts

Although Monero is a cryptocurrency, can it's infrastructure (blockchain + crypto functionality etc.) be harnessed to provide smart contract functionality?

Has anyone done work on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not by itself. See [Tari](https://www.tari.com/) for a secondary layer example.